# How to set and get jsp:useBean ArrayList class in jstl

Tags: jstl, usebean

usually in jsp , one could use an arrayList . I could create one as follows:

but how to set one is abit of a problem. for example, I want to add employee beans to it.

```
<c:forEach var ='employee' itmes = '${employeeList}'>
<c:set target = '${emplList}'value = '${employee}'/>
</c:forEeach>
```

When I ran this, I get error: Invalid property in <set>: "null". This seems like it wants me to provide the property attribute but do I really need it and what do i provide to it in my example?

Thanks

Comment: @BalusC,
I did check the link you provided and just as the questioner asked, his goal was to use the <c:set/> tag NOT use the <jsp:setProperty/> solution. I could  just use a c:set tag with map. why can't I do the same with arrayList?

Comment: @BalusC, sorry read my question again. I don't need to create any ListBean class to set a variable in the arrayList. I never had to because that is already created. I just need to set it and using the <:jsp setProperty /> is NOT what I want. if you feel as a boss closing the question. fine but your link doesn't answer my question.